# Mongo Cursor update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am using TypeScript/Javascript with Meteor/Mongo.

I am trying to update a cursor with a timestamp on its `lastMessageCreatedAt` field.

```
  updateChat(senderId: string, chatId: string): void {

    const chatExists = !!Chats.find(chatId).count();
    if (!chatExists) throw new Meteor.Error('chat-not-exists',
      'Chat doesn\'t exist');

    const chat1 = Chats.find(chatId);
    const receiverId = chat1.memberIds.find(memberId => memberId != senderId);  // <=== error TS2339: Property 'memberIds' does not exist on type 'Cursor<Chat>'.

    const chat = {
      memberIds: [senderId, receiverId],
      lastMessageCreatedAt: new Date()
    };

    Chats.update(chat);   // <=== error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
  },
```

model

```
  interface Chat {
    _id?: string;
    memberIds?: string[];
    title?: string;
    picture?: string;
    lastMessage?: Message;
    lastMessageCreatedAt?: Date;
    receiverComp?: Tracker.Computation;
    lastMessageComp?: Tracker.Computation;
  }
```

**Question**

However, I get the above errors. How do I update the cursor to have the timestamp? I am new to Meteor/Mongo, so I may be approaching this entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The update code is incorrect. It should be something like this

```
var date=new Date();

Chats.update({membersIds:{$all:[senderId,receiverId]}},{$set:{lastMessageCreatedAt: date}});
```

Refer [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this does not update. I don't see any errors either. The timestamp remains the same:   `{
    "_id": "8wca85kB7tHEudgjJ",
    "memberIds": [
      "P9",
      "J64"
    ],
    "lastMessageCreatedAt": "2016-09-16T16:13:35.942Z"
  }
]`

Comment: Hi, I have corrected the code. I missed `$all` operator.

Comment: Thanks.  I tested it, and it still does not update:  `[{"_id":"8wca85kB7tHEudgjJ","memberIds":["P9","J64"],"lastMessageCreatedAt":"2016-09-16T16:13:35.942Z"}]
app.bundle.js (line 481)
updateChat: P9, J64, Fri Sep 16 2016 21:34:45 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
app.bundle.js (line 483)
[{"_id":"8wca85kB7tHEudgjJ","memberIds":["P9","J64"],"lastMessageCreatedAt":"2016-09-16T16:13:35.942Z"}]`

Comment: ps. your example is missing a }. I changed it to:  `Chats.update({ membersIds: {$all:[senderId, receiverId] }}, { $set: { $lastMessageCreatedAt: date } });`

Comment: can you please print and confirm that receiverId retrieved here `const receiverId = chat1.memberIds.find(memberId => memberId != senderId);  ` is correct.

Comment: Still not working.  I obtain the `receiverId` as follows: `const receiverId: string = this.activeChat.memberIds.filter(function(value) {return value != that.senderId})[0];`. I do print it out, and it's correct: `'J64'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123566/discussion-between-ankit-and-richard).

Comment: This works, if you have the _id:  `Chats.update({ _id: chatId}, { $set: { lastMessageCreatedAt: date } });`

Answer (score 0):

First if there is a single chat, its preferable to use the mongo findOne(), rather than find(), especially if you are using record _id.  Remember the find(), or [findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) takes a query json object, and an optional projection (Mongo speak for the fields to return) json object. If the projection is omitted it returns all fields.

```
const chatFound = Chats.findOne(
   { '_id':
    { $eq: chatId},
   });
```

Similarly you can use the update() or [updateOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) mongo methods.  Just read the docs as they are slightly different, but essentially take a query, update, & options json object.

```
Chats.update(
  { '_id': 
    { $eq: chatId},
  },
  { 'memberIds': memberIds,
    'lastMessageCreatedAt': new Date()
  }
);
```

One Mongo feature that is very useful, but doesn't appear to be needed for your situation, is the upsert, which either inserts or updates a record....

```
Chats.update(
  { '_id': 
    { $eq: chatId},
  },
  { 'memberIds': memberIds,
    'lastMessageCreatedAt': new Date()
  },
  { upsert: true }
);
```

Finally remember you can use the Mongo command line to test your query before coding. Run Meteor Mongo from your terminal window.

Comment: Thank you Philip.  I will try it tomorrow when I'm  back at my pc.